# How to get rid of the untouchable yellow border of the ribbon menu-button?

Tags: wpf, ms-office, border, ribbon, controltemplate

I'm new to WPF control template and need your help on this.
I got a [sample Microsoft Ribbon project here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/ribbon-menu-button-yellow-border.rar). 
I tried to change the color of the ribbon menu button but I can not make the yellow border goes off. Please see screenshot below.

[image]

If you have a work-around, please help!

You can get MS Ribbon from:

1. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a desserted questions :(

Luckily after all, I found (cost 2 days) a work-around which uses the WPF Themes (download here [1](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&ProjectName=wpf) & [2](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962) (go to [WPF Themes on codeplex.com](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962#DownloadId=62512)) ) and change the brush whose key is `x:Key="&# 254;"`. [Here is my solution](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6194904/The%20Ribbon%20yellow%20border%20bug/WpfRibbonApplication1-%20SOLVED%20the%20yellow%20border%20bug.rar) which :

1. Change the "yellow" to white.
2. Coloring blue everything else that highlighted.
3. The red high light color is kept the same as the initial demo solution.
4. I marked my fix by *Fixed the "yellow-border bug" #1* & *Fixed the "yellow-border bug" #2*

This must be a bug of the Ribbon library since:

1. If don't use the WPF theme, the bug appears !?
2. The brushes #254 only got effective only if the a WPF theme used

It costs me so much time so I posted here to save the followers like me.

Hope this will help you!